# AttributeError: module 'discord.utils' has no attribute 'utcnow'

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Как решить ошибку?
Код:

```
@slash.slash(name="timeout", description="Ограничение доступа к чатом/каналом")
async def timeout(ctx, member: discord.Member, time, *, reason):
    time = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(time)
    await member.edit(until=discord.utils.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time), reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} получил за неадекватное поведение тайм-аут на {time}. Причина: {reason}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде код работает, протестил, не забудьте прописать в начале кода `import datetime`

```py
@slash.slash(name="timeout", description="Ограничение доступа к чатом/каналом")
async def timeout(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason):
    await member.edit(timed_out_until=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time), reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} получил за неадекватное поведение тайм-аут на {time}. Причина: {reason}")
```

P.S. про тайм-аут реально не знал(

Comment: Просто не из-за чего проблема появилась с этой командой... Так что пока не могу проверить сам.

Comment: `async def timeout(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason):`

Пишет: **TypeError: Protocols with non-method members don't support issubclass()**